# Ruby on Rails : where is stored the error message from the Active record method "validates_uniqueness_of"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

how to retrieve the message from a validates_uniqueness_of method that turns out false?

So i can choose to display it in an appropriated place on my view.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the errors like so:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
person = Person.new(:name => "JD")
person.valid? # => false
person.errors[:name] # => ["has already been taken"]
```

Read about validation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#working-with-validation-errors)